# Count the number of times a word happens between two dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What formula can I use to find a specific word between two dates?

I know I can use countifs to find the word for the entire column - but is it possible to do so between two dates?

I've been trying to combine these two formulas to no avail

=countifs(C8:C182,">="&C6,C8:C182,"<="&D6) - this has the dates and can find the amount of times a deal is created.

=countifs(F8:F187,D1) - this can find the amount of times a certain type of deal comes up.

In the image I want to find out what is D and E without having to manually count/ split the data by date aha.

[image]

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you using Sheets or Excel?

Comment: can you share copy of spreadsheet without sensitive data? Could help us replicate specially on the dates

Comment: Use `QUERY()` function.

Comment: Using sheets. The image shows what it looks like - you can use any dates, deal stage, type and amount. @Harun24HR Though I have used query before I'm not too versed. What would the formula look like?

Comment: share a copy /sample of your sheet with example of desired output